# Content porting with limited permissions

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

We want to limit the permissions for users i.e. not to provide system admin access to all the users. When a non-admin user tries to port the content, we are getting the error at the time of exporting the content: "Failed to resolve mappings in application data SiteEdit" however there is option to skip the error.

Given below is the details of exception. What permission is required to resolve this issue?

```
Error details:
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault, Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b]]: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault]: You do not have permission to perform this action. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem on Tridion forum. [Tridion Article](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-content-porter-2009-sp1-for-dtap-4.aspx)

Essentially, when you perform import in content porting, the publication metadata and other information is also retrieved and tried to be ported. To avoid this from happening, while importing selected children only which will not select any additional items and only will select the required items.

After performing above steps, even non-admin can content-port the items on which they have access to.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using a Non-Administrator user to run Content Porter, then you need to look for all the dependencies of the Items that you are accessing.

In order to export/import an Item through Content Porter running using a Non-Administrator user, it is necessary that the Specific Item as well as all the dependencies of that Item must have Read/Write Access.

Comment: While porting the content, I have done following two things which should take care of dependencies: selected all in the exclusion list of dependencies and while porting selected only children to be ported. Even after choosing these options I am getting above error so can you please suggest how can I handle this?

Comment: What if you have permission on the Component but not on the Category with which a field is defined in the schema of that component?

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you have succeeded in identifying the publication metadata as the cause of the problem (although it does look like a different problem, as you started with an export problem) However the more general case is that content porter is telling you "You do not have permission to perform this action", and you don't know which item is involved.

To identify the problematic items you can look in the event log on the Tridion CM server, where authorization failures are logged as warnings. Simply monitor the log as you run your export (or import) and you can get more information about your problem.